# HA is not enabled for this namenode when using "hdfs zkfc -formatZK"

Tags: java, hadoop

I am establishing a single node hadoop cluster using zookeeper
my zookeeper cluster has three nodes which on the same machine with different ports.they are working fine.
my hadoop cluster has only one node.my hadoop and zookeepers are on the same machine.when using "hdfs zkfc -formatZK" they tells me:Exception in thread "main" org.apache.Hadoop.HadoopIllegalArgumentException: HA is not enabled for this namenode

my core-site.xml:

```xml
<configuration>
 <property>    
      <name>fs.defaultFS</name>    
      <value>hdfs://yavin</value>    
 </property>
 <property>
      <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
      <value>/usr/local/hadoop/hdfs/temp</value>
 </property>                             
 <property>    
      <name>io.file.buffer.size</name>    
      <value>4096</value>    
 </property>
 <property>
      <name>ha.zookeeper.quorum</name>
      <value>coruscant:2181,coruscant:2182,coruscant:2183</value>
 </property>
 </configuration>
```

coruscant is mapping my ip address in hosts file. all my zookeepers are on coruscant using port 2181 2182 2183

my hdfs-site.xml:

```xml
<configuration>   
    <property>    
        <name>dfs.nameservices</name>    
        <value>yavin</value>    
    </property>  
    <property>
       <name>dfs.ha.namenodes.yavin</name>
       <value>nn1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
       <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.yavin.nn1</name>
       <value>coruscant:9000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.yavin.nn1</name>
        <value>coruscant:50070</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address.yavin.nn1</name>
        <value>coruscant:53310</value>
    </property>
    <property>
         <name>dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir</name>
         <value>qjournal://coruscant:8485;coruscant:8486;coruscant:8487/yavin</value>
    </property>
    <property>
          <name>dfs.journalnode.edits.dir</name>
          <value>/usr/local/hadoop/journal</value>
    </property>
    <property>
          <name>dfs.ha.automatic-failover.enabled</name>
          <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.yavin</name>
            <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider</value>
    </property>
    <property>
             <name>dfs.ha.fencing.methods</name>
             <value>sshfence</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>dfs.ha.fencing.ssh.private-key-files</name>
            <value>/root/.ssh/id_rsa</value>
    </property>                              
    <property>    
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>    
        <value>file:///usr/local/hadoop/hdfs/name</value>    
    </property>    
    <property>    
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>    
        <value>file:///usr/local/hadoop/hdfs/data</value>    
    </property>    
    <property>    
       <name>dfs.replication</name>    
       <value>2</value>    
    </property>                                                                     <property>    
       <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>    
       <value>true</value>    
    </property>    
<property>
        <name>dfs.permissions.enable</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.permissions</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

my mapred-site.xml:

```xml
<configuration>
 <property>    
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>    
        <value>yarn</value>    
 </property>    
</configuration>
```

my yarn-site.xml:

```xml
<configuration>
    <property>
           <name>yarn.resourcemanager.ha.enabled</name>
           <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>    
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>    
            <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>    
     </property>  
     <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
            <value>coruscant</value>
      </property> 
</configuration>
```

what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. After reading the source code of [`HAUtil.isHAEnabled()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/2.2.0/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/HAUtil.java#HAUtil.isHAEnabled(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration%2Cjava.lang.String)) I found the solution:

HDFS high availabilty is only available when you have **more than one namenode** configured. The error message is still a little misleading, though.